# How to get identity from database using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am new to Linq-to-SQL.

I want to retrieve the identity value from Linq-to-SQL while using `DBContext.SubmitChanges()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should automatically update your record. Something like this:

```
Customer cust = new Customer();
 cust.Company = "blah";
context.Customers.Add( cust );
context.SubmitChanges();
int NewPk = cust.Pk;
```

Answer (score 2):

After you have called `SubmitChanges()` you can access the id field of your object to retrieve the ID.